# How to change a statistic's collation or remove its dependency from database collation in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have decided to change my SQL Server database collation; however it gives me the common schema-bound error.

> The database collation cannot be changed if a schema-bound object depends on it

There are several objects listed on the error list above, including some constraints and statistics. I have no problem with removing the constraints' dependencies. My only problem is removing the statistics' dependencies.

The exact error is:

> The statistics 'SampleStatistics' is dependent on database collation. The database collation cannot be changed if a schema-bound object depends on it. Remove the dependencies on the database collation and then retry the operation.

Here are some notes:

1. I cannot delete the statistic, because the `Delete` option is disabled.
2. I cannot generate the statistic's script, because the `Script Statistic as` option is disabled.
3. I have found the statistic in `sys.stats`, but I cannot delete the record and I get this error:

> Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.
> 4) There isn't any way to change the collation or remove the dependency in the statistic's `Properties` option.

Is there anyway to solve the problem?

Comment: Even if SSMS doesn't offer the option, `DROP STATISTICS` should still work even for system-generated statistics. Note that changing the DB collation is sufficiently tedious that you're typically better off scripting it anew altogether and copying over data, rather than playing whack-a-mole with every column in every object.

Comment: Easiest way to change collation is to create new tables with the correct collation, move data into those tables and then drop the old tables etc, rename the new table.

Comment: @JeroenMostert we want to upgrade a software which is connected to SSMS; however there are some problem after the update. That's why we need to change the database collation. If I drop the statistic, then how can I recreate it?

Comment: @M.Ali there are too many tables to do that. But we're considering it as the last option.

Comment: Well sometimes it is a lot of work but its gotta be done :)

Comment: @M.Ali there's also another problem which is by not changing the database collation, the new tables would still have the same problem. Therefore we have to change the database collation, in order to prevent that from happening.

Comment: You cannot/should not recreate the statistic; the system will do that automatically when it's needed (just as it did initially), assuming the `AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS` database option is on. If you want you can call `sp_createstats` manually (after all statistics have been dropped).

Comment: The statistics are created by the index and queries so if you drop the indexes the related statistics will be removed. On the other hand, you can use the DROP STATISTICS command which is not related to the indexes.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I didn't know such SP existed. Thanks for sharing it. Also previously when you said it's better to create a new database, did you mean by generating the script of current database and creating a new one?

Comment: @esat Thanks for the reply. It worked just fine. Feel free to post it as the answer.

Comment: Yes, I meant scripting the entire database (excluding collation, obviously) and using the script to create a new one (making sure it has the collation you want), then using the data import/export wizard to copy over data (for optimal speed, create indexes and constraints only afterwards). Assuming no columns are using a custom collation that differs from the DB default, this would change everything in one go. Note that changing collation can lead to key violations (depending on what collation you're changing to) so creating a new DB and copying over data is safer, to boot.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for the tip. I'll try doing this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Statistics are database objects which involve the detailed
> statistical distribution of the column values for the tables or
> indexed views. The query optimizer uses this information to estimate
> how many rows will be returned from a query.

When we create an index the statistics are created automatically which are related to the index. If we drop the index the statistics which are related to the index will be dropped.

On the other hand, the queries can create statistics in their first execution and we can drop these statistics as like the below query :

```
DROP STATISTICS table_name.statistics_name | view.statistics_name [ ,...n ]
```